# C# Mailkit Search and if condition

Tags: c#, mailkit

i dont know if this is easy or not but i am trying to validate a search query in mailkit
and some jobs like

```
var query = SearchQuery.BodyContains("searchforsoemthink1").Or(SearchQuery.BodyContains("searchforsomethink2"));
foreach (var uid in sent.Search(query))
{
...check if condition 1 is true SearchQuery.BodyContains("searchforsoemthink1") and some jobs
...check if condition 2 is true SearchQuery.BodyContains("searchforsomethink2") and do some jobs}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this would be to run multiple search queries.